# Jquery: remove $('#id').on(...) listener when element's id is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

I am trying to change the functionality of a HTML form submit button when it's been submitted (by changing the form's id) to work as a toggle.  However, when the id of the form is changed, the on('submit',function) is not updated and is still called despite the id not being tied to the form anymore.  `update_favourite(...)` is being called inside an AJAX function but I've removed the AJAX from this snippet for simplicity's sake

```
                $('#add_favourite').on('submit', function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    console.log('add');
                    update_favourite('add');
                });

                $('#remove_favourite').on('submit', function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    console.log('remove');
                    update_favourite('remove');
                });


                function update_favourite(addOrRemove) {
                     if($('#add_favourite').length){
                        $('#remove_favourite').attr("onclick","");
                        $('#submitbutton').val('Remove from Favourites');
                        $('#add_favourite').attr("id","remove_favourite"); 
                    /*This doesn't make a difference
                        $('#remove_favourite').on('submit', function(event){
                            event.preventDefault();
                            console.log('remove');
                            update_favourite('remove');
                        });
                    */

                    }
                    else if($('#remove_favourite').length){
                        $('#remove_favourite').attr("onclick","");
                        $('#submitbutton').val('Add to Favourites');
                        $('#remove_favourite').attr("id","add_favourite");  
                    /*This doesn't make a difference 
                        $('#add_favourite').on('submit', function(event){
                            event.preventDefault();
                            console.log('add');
                            update_favourite('add');
                        });

                   */
                    }

                };
```

My implementation changes the submit button and form id correctly, but the onclick listener does not change with the id changing.  Any suggestions/corrections would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you disable the button with `.prop("disabled", true)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone posted the correct answer but deleted it before I could try it, and after some playing around I was able to implement what I think the deleted answer was telling me.

Their answer was changing `$('#add_favourite').on('submit', function(event){` to `$(document.body).on('submit', '#add_favourite', function(event){` and adding `$(document.body).off('submit', 'remove_favourite');` to remove the listener.

Whatever happened to the original commenter, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use **off** method like
 `$('#add_favourite').off('submit')`
to remove previous event handler and then add new event handler with updated id using **on** method.

Edit :

jsfiddle(in comment) and my solution aren't working because form submit refreshes the page.

If we change the button type to button from submit then it'll work
following code worked for me

```
$('#add_favourite').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#log').text('add');
    update_favourite('add');

});
function update_favourite(addOrRemove) {
    if ($('#add_favourite').length) {
        $('#add_favourite').off('click');
        console.log('add favourite is being removed');
        $('#submitbutton').val('Remove from Favourites');
        $('#add_favourite').attr("id", "remove_favourite");
        $('#remove_favourite').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#log').text('remove');
            console.log('remove');
            update_favourite('remove');
        });

    } else if ($('#remove_favourite').length) {
        console.log('remove favourite is being removed');
        $('#remove_favourite').off('click');
        $('#submitbutton').val('Add to Favourites');
        $('#remove_favourite').attr("id", "add_favourite");
        $('#add_favourite').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log('add');
            update_favourite('add');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/be6jfgqw/
For some reason the submit button breaks jsfiddle, could you help me figure out why first?

Comment: nevermind, I posted the correct answer.  thanks anyway!